# Need a help in building (Qt5.1.1)qtmultimedia with gstreamer

Tags: arm, cross-compiling, gstreamer, qt5.1, qtmultimedia

Hi all i don't know where exactly i should ask this question. i am stuck from past 1 week trying this out.
I am trying to crosscompile Qt 5.1.1 qtmultimedia with gstreamer on imx6 arm based device. This is my config file:

```
#!/bin/sh
./configure —prefix=/tools/rootfs/usr/local/qt-5.1.1 -examplesdir /tools/rootfs/usr/local/qt-5.1.1/examples -verbose -opensource -confirm-license -make libs -make examples -device imx6 \
-device-option CROSS_COMPILE=\
/opt/freescale/usr/local/gcc-4.6.2-glibc-2.13-linaro-multilib-2011.12/fsl-linaro-    toolchain/bin/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi- \
-no-pch -no-opengl -no-icu -no-xcb -no-c++11 \
-opengl es2 \
-eglfs \
-compile-examples \
-glib -gstreamer \
```

this is my qmake.conf:

```
include(../common/linux_device_pre.conf) ROOTFS=/tools/rootfs EGLFS_PLATFORM_HOOKS_SOURCES = $$PWD/qeglfshooks_imx6.cpp

QMAKE_INCDIR += $$ROOTFS/usr/include \ $$ROOTFS/usr/include/glib-2.0 \ 
$$ROOTFS/usr/include/glib-2.0/gio \ $$ROOTFS/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib \
 $$ROOTFS/usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject \ $$ROOTFS/usr/include/glib-2.0/include
 $$ROOTFS/usr/include/gstreamer-0.10 \ $$ROOTFS/usr/include/libxml2 

QMAKE_LIBDIR += $$ROOTFS/usr/lib 
QMAKE_LIBS += -L/tools/rootfs/usr/lib -lgthread-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lglib-2.0 - lgmodule-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lgstbase-0.10 -lgstcontroller-0.10 -lgstreamer-0.10 

QMAKE_INCDIR_OPENGL_ES2+= $$ROOTFS/usr/include/GLES2
QMAKE_LIBDIR_OPENGL_ES2+= $$ROOTFS/usr/lib QMAKE_LIBS_EGL += -lEGL   
QMAKE_LIBS_OPENGL_ES2 += -lGLESv2 -lEGL -lGAL 
QMAKE_LIBS_OPENVG += -lOpenVG -lEGL -lGAL
 QMAKE_LFLAGS += -Wl,-rpath-link,$$ROOTFS/usr/lib 
IMX6_CFLAGS = -march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon -DLINUX=1 -DEGL_API_FB=1 
IMX6_CFLAGS_RELEASE = -O2 $$IMX6_CFLAGS 
QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE += $$IMX6_CFLAGS_RELEASE   
  QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += $$IMX6_CFLAGS_RELEASE

 QMAKE_CFLAGS_DEBUG += $$IMX6_CFLAG
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_DEBUG += $$IMX6_CFLAGS include(../common/linux_device_post.conf) load(qt_config)
```

when i configured gstreamer was enabled. 
but it was not building multimedia. i went to qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.1.1 and did make module qtmultimedia. after make install i tried to run my application on the device. it says:
QtMultimedia : defaultServiceProvider::requestService(): no service found for – “org.qt-project.qt.mediaplayer”

according to qtmultimedia config.log package gstreamer-0.10 not found. after that tried to build it exporting PKG_CONFIG_PATH
still result is same. can any one please help me solve this error!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

exporting package config path was not proper due to which configuration was failing:

export PKG_CONFIG_DIR=
export PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=${SYSROOT}/usr/lib/pkgconfig:${SYSROOT}/usr/share/pkgconfig
export PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR=${SYSROOT}

configure and build again.